# Automatic updates are not detected

Tags: apt, upgrade, software-installation, updates

The system does not make automatic updates, and there is a red and white 
 circular symbol in the notifications area. However I'm able to do updates from commande line.

**sudo apt-get update** gives:

```
   Ign http://linux.dropbox.com trusty InRelease
Ign http://dl.google.com stable InRelease                           
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                      
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                        
Hit http://linux.dropbox.com trusty Release.gpg                                
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg                          
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease               
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://linux.dropbox.com trusty Release                                    
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release                                        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://linux.dropbox.com trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg                               
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main amd64 Packages                            
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://linux.dropbox.com trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Sources                      
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Sources                
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Sources                  
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Sources                
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages               
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages           
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages         
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main i386 Packages
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted i386 Packages
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-it                
Ign http://linux.dropbox.com trusty/main Translation-en            
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe i386 Packages
Ign http://linux.dropbox.com trusty/main Translation-it
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Sources
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Sources
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Sources
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Sources
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release       
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Sources
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Sources
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Sources
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-it                       
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en                 
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-it                 
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en                 
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-it                 
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en                   
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-it                   
Reading package lists... Done
```

and **sudo apt-get update** gives:

```
   Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
```

What could be the problem? And how can i fix it?

**UPDATE**
This is an snapshot of my desktop:  http://s16.imagestime.com/out.php/i1140776_ImageProblem.png

top right, there is the symbol problem of which I spoke.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. 1) Run commands with `LANG=C` in front of them. This way they will give outpit in English. 2) I don't see any problems.

Comment: Is the second command `sudo apt-get upgrade`? So what is the problem? The 3 packages that are not upgraded?

Comment: @Pilot Well done, and thank you for your welcome. I know that it seem no problems..... but automatic updates don't work

Comment: @Pilot6 No, the problem is that automatic updates from gui (graphics interface) don't work, although manually from the command line I can update the system

Comment: What do you mean by "don't work"? There are no updates. You can run `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` to upgrade those 3 held packages, but nothing else is available.

Comment: @Pilot6 I did the upgrade and then I got the command back. The output you see is on the commands after I have upgraded. However, even before making these updates manually, they were not detected automatically (what has been happening since about 1 month)

Comment: @Pilot [http://s16.imagestime.com/out.php/i1140776_ImageProblem.png](http://s16.imagestime.com/out.php/i1140776_ImageProblem.png) is a visualization of problem

Comment: What do you see when you click on the red and white circular symbol?

Comment: @edwinksl I see:  

There was a problem checking updates